# Create Infobubble in Taskbar Java

Tags: java, taskbar, info, infobubble

i would like to know if there is a possibility to generate an Infobubble in the taskbar like in the picture. So, if something is happening in my Java program then show the Infobubble.

Is this possible in Java?

Thanks for Answers!

[image]

Comment: Which toolkit are you using? awt/swing/fx?

Comment: until now i used swing, but if there is no way with swing im open to learn other toolkits...but i prefer swing :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it...link shows you how to add notification to system tray.

[solved](http://www.javaknowledge.info/how-to-add-notification-to-system-tray-in-java/)